# Matrix Exponentiation involving Invertible Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on, if A is invertible, showing that $Ae^MA^{-1}=e^{AMA^{-1}}$

I understand that $e^M=\sum \frac{M^k}{k!}$  but how does A also move into the exponent? Any help appreciated!

Comment: $A\frac{M^k}{k!}A^{-1}={\frac{(AMA^{-1})^k}{k!}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(A M A^{-1})^k=\underbrace{A M A^{-1}A M A^{-1}\ldots A M A^{-1}}_{k ~~\text{times}}$, since $A^{-1}A=I$, we'll have $(A M A^{-1})^k=A M I M I\ldots I M A^{-1}=A M^k A^{-1}$, now by substitution, you'll have the proof:

Since, $e^M=\sum \frac{M^k}{k!}$, you have:

$A e^M A^{-1}=A\sum \frac{M^k}{k!}A^{-1}=\sum \frac{A M^k A^{-1}}{k!}=\sum \frac{(A M A^{-1})^k}{k!}=e^{A M A^{-1}}$